# Syncing Core Data changes with the apple watch takes too long

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, apple-watch

I am sharing a UIManagedDocument with my apple watch extension and everything seems to work well. I can query managed objects from my database perfectly. The problem comes when i edit one of those objects. That change is not reflected in the watch app until ~30 seconds later. I repeat the query a number of times, but it's no good until that period passes.

I have tried forcing a save in the managedObjectContext, making double sure i'm running in the main thread, but i just can't get that update immediately.

Is there something else i should do here? or is this a simulator/apple watch limitation?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have to fully close the app to see changes between watch and phone